# How to deploy a Laravel project to a shared hosting server: 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: laravel, server

I have a problem deploying Laravel to a shared hosting server.

This is how the the directory looks in the server.

```
|-Laravel(contents of Laravel project folders and files except public folder)  
|
|-public_html  
       |  
       |-example.com(default subfolder))  
             |  
             |-contents of Laravel public folder
```

I created a folder called "Laravel" at the same level where the public_html folder is and threw all the Laravel project folders and files(except public folder) in there. Then I took everything that was in the public folder and put it in a subfolder in public_html.

Next I changed the index.php file like in the image.
[image: index.php]

I also changed .env file too(APP_ENV=production and APP_URL).

At this point I think I should be able to see something when I access to http://www.example.com/ but I get a 500 Internal Server Error.

My Laravel is version 7.15.0.

I appreciate if you could tell me what I'm doing wrong or what I should do. Any help would be appreciated as I have tried multiple methods with no success.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow, toyop! One question: Did you create-import the database and database user? And did you set APP_DEBUG=false at the .env? Also get sure to grant the correct righs to the "logs" folder (755).

Answer (score 0):

within the index.php file, after where `$app` is defined, add in the following line

```
$app->bind('path.public`, function() {
   return __DIR__;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, in shared hosts you have to symlink the `public` directory of your Laravel project as `public_html` in your server.

You can deploy your project to any folder in your server, including the public folder. Then just symlink the public directory as `public_html`, using the `ln -s` linux command:

```sh
ln -s <PATH TO THE ORIGINAL PUBLIC FOLDER> <PATH TO public_html/example.com>
```

> Note that you should `rm -rf public_html/example.com` directoy before creating the symlink

Comment: Thank you for your comments guys,
I wasn't familiar with linux command so I was following the protocol in this website([Deploy a laravel 7 app to shared hosting](https://dev.to/fractalbit/deploy-a-laravel-7-app-to-shared-hosting-4eac) ). It says to create create-symlink.php in public_html and access to http://yourdomain/myapp/create-symlink.php. I tried doing this but 500 error showed.